# Query is working and giving accurate result in mysql but is resulting in a java.lang.nullpointerexception in jsp

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, netbeans

I have used the sum function to calculate the total and then save it in another table. When i run this on mysql, it provides the right result. But when included in the jsp, it ends in java.lang.NullPointerException
[You can see the same query working in mysql here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtvt9.jpg)
[The error generated on running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCbqu.jpg)

```
rst = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * 
                         FROM invoicename 
                         ORDER BY name DESC 
                         LIMIT 1;");

if (rst.next()) {
    String str = rst.getString("name");

    rst1 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT sum(price) 
                              FROM invoices 
                              WHERE invoicename='" + str + "';");
    if (rst1.next()) {
        int s = rst1.getInt(1);
        if (rst1.wasNull()) {
            s = 0;
        }

        stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO invoice 
                            VALUES('" + str + "',curdate(),curtime(),'" + s + "')");
    }
```

Comment: Could you please add full stack trace?

Comment: compile-single-jsp:
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
Compiling 1 source file to E:\all in coding\netbeans\POS\build\generated\classes
Note: E:\all in coding\netbeans\POS\build\generated\src\org\apache\jsp\payed_002dnewbill_002dfunc_jsp.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: E:\all in coding\netbeans\POS\build\generated\src\org\apache\jsp\payed_002dnewbill_002dfunc_jsp.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 17 seconds)

Comment: @CAMOBAP there are 3 notes, at the end of trace. But i do no understand, what to do to fix it.

Comment: looks like you attached `jsp` compilation log, which doesn't related to original issue `NPE`, could you please reproduce problem again and provide NPE stack trace?

Comment: @CAMOBAP here is the link, for the full stack trace - http://pastebin.ca/3404364